# Conditional select dictionary value in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
varpr = {'values': ['pr', 'tas'],
 'names': ['Precipitation [mm]', 'Temperature [C deg]']}
```

How can I select `names` field if `values == pr`?
I expect something like `x = 'Precipitation [mm]'`

T try:

```
var = 'pr'
[v for k,v in varpr.items() if k == 'values' and v == 'pr']
```

but got null.

Comment: Do you mean by index between the two list values? I think your dictionary is the wrong way around, try using `{name: value for name, value in zip(varpr['names'], varpr['values'])}`, then a lookup by name is trivial (and O(1)).

Comment: Your question isn't clear. If you just want the value of `'names'` where the list contains `'Precipitation [mm]'`, then `x = varpr['names'][0]` and `print(x)`, should give you that.

Comment: @amanb but this is not conditional. I need to use 'pr' in my query

Comment: What do you mean "select names field if values == pr?" ? "values" is a list, and so is "names".

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think the OP actually wants it the other way round (get the matching "names" item from the values): `{value:name for value, name in zip(varpr['values'], varpr['names'])}.get('pr')`;

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers oh good point, the other way around seemed more logical to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below to get required output:

```
[k for k,v in zip(varpr['names'], varpr['values']) if v == 'pr']

#  ['Precipitation [mm]']
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly more appropriate is to define a new, restructured dictionary. Then just query the dictionary:

```
d = dict(zip(varpr['values'], varpr['names']))

print(d)
# {'pr': 'Precipitation [mm]', 'tas': 'Temperature [C deg]'}

print(d['pr'])
# Precipitation [mm]
```